# Issue in calculating elapsed time in millisecond date command not found

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, date

I have the following code trying to calculate how much time it takes in milliseconds to build a docker container. However I am facing syntax error and command not found issue, running bash script bash pipeline.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 'Initiating pipeline'
cd /home/switch-approach/server-c
start=date+'%s%3N'
sudo docker build -t server-c .
end=date+'%s%3N'
echo "duration: $((duration=end-start)) seconds."

Retrieving error date+'%s%3N' command not found 
operand expected syntax error start
```

Comment: You want `start=$(date ...)` (and also for `end`).

Comment: @muru thanks for your help I am still receiving date command not found error. the syntax error is gone

Comment: put a space between date command and plus parameter

Comment: @D'ArcyNader, thank you so much its working perfectly fine now, didn't realised that it was a silly mistake. You save my day